# how to have a vm image act as a server host

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, web-server, vmware-player

I have a VM Ware player, VMware-player-3.0.1-227600.exe

I downloaded a cent os image, it's version is

CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

I have apache installed and listening on port 8080. However when I visit my ip address, x.x.x.x.:8080/

I don't get the default apache page as I would by going to localhost:8080/

What do I have to do in my image or vmware to get it to serve?

I forgot to mention, I'm hosting the image from a Windows XP 64 machine, and I host fine using that, so the router isn't the issue.

Comment: "Your" IP address?

Comment: Yes, not the local IP address but the ISP-provided IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does VMware Player come with a virtual network editor?  I suspect that the issue is your VM is running on either a host-only network (only between the VM and the host) or a NAT'd network (network connections from the VM are NAT'd out and appear to come from the host itself as far as the rest of the world is concerned; this is effectively a firewall protecting the VM).  Either way, connecting to your IP address isn't going to get you anywhere.

If VMware Player lets you change the VM's virtual adapter is connected to, change it to be on the "Bridged" network.  If you have a DHCP server, the Vm will pick up its own lease when started; if not, you'll have to pick an IP address within your network scope that isn't in use.  Then whichever way, you connect to the VM as if it was a real system with its own IP.

If you have a network/sysadmin responsible for this network, asking him/her for advice would probably be best so that you don't pick something already in use.